# Titanium SDK 5.1.2 and now 5.2.0 would both not fire events in some cases in an iOS app

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have an iOS app that compiles and works fine with Titanium SDK 5.1.1GA but it would not work correctly with either of 5.1.2 GA or 5.2.0 GA.

The issue is with a scrollView in which events are not being fired with the newer SDKs. It is a lot of code to post all of it. The scrollView is the last of four in a ScrollableView and it is being created like this:

```
function SettingsView() {

    var self = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    });
    var helpButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: "HELP",
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
        height: Ti.UI.FILL,
        color: "black",
    });

    self.add(helpButton);
    helpButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        Ti.API.info("helpButton> Clicked!!");
    });
    helpButton.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){
        Ti.API.info("helpButton> touchstart!");
    });
    helpButton.addEventListener("touchend", function(){
        Ti.UI.info("helpButton> touchend!");
    });
    return self;
}
```

The default animation on the button is working - I can see the color changing as I tap on it - but none of the events are fired.

Elsewhere in the code events on views and buttons are working with the newer SDKs.

I have tried all sorts of things but have not been able to make the events on objects inside that scroll view fire. The only thing that has worked so far is changing the SDK to 5.1.1 or earlier.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: So if I follow you correctly, you have a ScrollableView where each view is a ScrollView? I'm not surprised that may cause unexpected behaviour. That said, if it works correctly in 5.1.1 but not in 5.1.2 (or later) then that can be considered a regression bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is a bug but it is kind of being tossed around. According to [TIMOB-20493] (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20493?jql=text%20~%20%225.1.2%22) the change between 5.1.1 and 5.1.2 is really in the default value of run-on-main-thread - it is no longer set to true. And indeed setting that to true in tiapp.xml resolves the problem. .... There is some issue with the ScrollableView though. Once run-on-main-thread is set to false, events generate 100% in the first view and you do not always get them in the rest of the views with the last one being the worst...

Comment: I guess I was too quick to comment. Adding <run-on-main-thread>true</run-on-main-thread> to tiapp.xml does solve the original problem but creates others - events on other views now are not being fired. Going back to 5.1.1 GA for the time being. NOTE: having run-on-main-thread in tiapp.xml with 5.1.1 is even a bigger disaster althought it was supposedly true by default so to go back to 5.1.1 and have a working app I had to remove it. ... I thought this might be of help to someone...

Comment: Let's continue discussing this issue on https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20493, which has been reopened.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, tracked at the Appcelerator JIRA:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20493